# how to enable CORS in ASP.NET MVC Controller Level in WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I am working on WebApi and CORS is enabled for WebAPI.config level but it is not enabled for MVC Controller?
I am not asking about .Net CORE!

Comment: I don't think so @Mikev, look at the tags, he doesn't ask for .NET Core specifically

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

It says:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

So use the EnableCors attribute. Good luck.